# How to change the style of primefaces checkbox(selectBooleanCheckbox) to normal JSF 2 checkbox?

Tags: primefaces

Need to change the CSS style of the primefaces checkbox. What are all the style class responsible for changing the style of the checkbox?

```css
.ui-chkbox{
display:inline !important;
}
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box
{
width:10px !important;
height:10px !important;
-moz-border-radius:2px !important;
-webkit-border-radius:2px !important;
border-radius:2px !important;
}

.ui-chkbox-icon.ui-icon-check
{
background-position:center;
}

.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-label{
cursor:pointer !important;
margin:1px 0 0 1px !important;
outline:medium none !important;
z-index:1 !important;
display:inline-block !important;
vertical-align:top !important;
}
```

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version are you using? Which component are you talking about? I cannot see any `p:selectOneCheckbox` component

Comment: I am using primefaces with version 5.2  need to change the style of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` that resembles like `h:selectBooleanCheckBox`

Comment: I would be glad to help you but there is no `selectOneCheckbox` component in PF 5.2. Maybe you are using `selectCheckboxMenu`,  `selectManyCheckbox` or `selectBooleanCheckbox`?

Comment: Sorry it is `p:selectBooleanCheckBox` not `selectOneCheckbox`

Comment: Why not just use a normal jsf checkbox?

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje I am forced to use the primefaces `p:selectBooleanCheckBox` for some scenario. But in the application most of the pages I am using `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` to make the application look and feel consistent I need to change the style of primefaces checkbox look and feel that resembles like JSF  checkbox.

Comment: Forced by whom? By or by what requirement. Maybe you can solve it with a plain jsf component but do not know how

Comment: Inside datatable I am using `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" styleClass="styleColumn5"  />` it will render the checkbox in the header and it will render the checkbox in all the rows while selecting the header chekbox it will select all the rows. Refer this link [Checkbox based Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml). I need the change the style of those checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, but that is **not** a `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`. It is the selectbox inside the datatable. Please change the subject of your question and add this info to the introduction in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using PrimeFaces 5.2, you can check all the skinning CSS classes in the current [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) and page 411, in particular, which gives you details about `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`

> **.ui-chkbox** Main container element.
>   **.ui-chkbox-box** Container of checkbox icon.
>   **.ui-chkbox-icon** Checkbox icon.
>   **.ui-chkbox-label** Checkbox label.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu for your quick response, But i already refereed the above class I can able to reduce the size of the checkbox but the tick mark for the checkbox is not properly fitting into the checkbox. Do you have any idea about how to adjust the tick mark according the modified checkbox size that will be very much helpful to me?

Comment: It's difficult to fix your CSS issue without any code or any screenshots. Maybe you can tweak your CSS with `text-indent` or `background-position` on `.ui-chkbox-icon.ui-icon-check`

Comment: `
.ui-chkbox{display:inline !important;}  
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box  
{  
width:10px !important;  
height:10px !important;  
-moz-border-radius:2px !important;  
-webkit-border-radius:2px !important;  
border-radius:2px !important;  
}  

.ui-chkbox-icon.ui-icon-check{  
background-position:center;  

}  

.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-label{  
cursor:pointer !important;  
margin:1px 0 0 1px !important;  
outline:medium none !important;  
z-index:1 !important;  
display:inline-block !important;  
vertical-align:top !important;  
}  
`
The above CSS class I am using for the modification

Comment: Please edit your initial post instead. Comments are not the right place to show your code. In addition you should add a screenshot to show what is not laid out.

Comment: Hai Mathieu , I added the CSS code for the problem but  I am unable to attach the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this same problem using these CSS codes:

```
.indivcheckbox .ui-chkbox-icon {
    background-position-x: -66px;
    background-position-y: -147px;
}

.indivcheckbox .ui-icon-check {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
```

While my component is this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="indivcheckbox" />
```

Basically you just make the box small and then adjust the check icon by tinkering on the background-position-(x/y) to center it in.

Hope it helps.